# SF Community Chatbot and Chatter in Web Application (not lightning)

Tags: community

I have enabled Chatbot and Chatter in SF and want to implement the same or similar interface and functionalities in my C# web application (website).

Is it possible? If it is, is there any API I can use in C#? and any document please?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of options depending on the full function range of your C# web stack:

1. If you can implement custom Javascript:

- You can use [Lightning-Out](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_considerations.htm) to implement a [Lightning component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceChatter:feed/documentation) that hosts a chatter feed through the `<forceChatter:feed/>` tag.
- Lightning-out is used to embed Lightning Components outside of Salesforce Lightning domains. You'll need to [provide a Salesforce session token](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_authentication.htm) to authenticate as your Salesforce user.
- As for Chat, if you can implement Javascript then you can take advantage of [Embedded Service Deployments](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_create_deployment.htm&type=5) and add a custom Javascript code snippet to your site.

2. If you do all scripting through C# and can't implement Javascript

- You'll need to use REST APIs for [Chatter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/connect_resources_feed_elements.htm) and [Live Agent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_API_requests.htm) to connect your implementation.
- Authentication and response processing will be entirely up to your application